# choose $k$ suitable for cubic equation

Tags: complex-analysis, cubics

So i started with the equation 
$$z^3+az^2+bz+c=0,$$
with $z\in\mathbb{C}$. I've set $z=w+h$ and chose $h=-\frac{1}{3}a$ to get the equation
\begin{align}
w^3+Bw+C=0,
\end{align}
with 
\begin{align*}
B&= -\frac{1}{3}a^2+b \\
C&= \frac{2}{27}a^3-\frac{1}{3}ab+c.
\end{align*}

Now I'm asked to take $w=kv$ and to manipulate $w^3+Bw+C=0$ into 
$$4v^3-3v+A=0.$$

First I thought to take $k^3=4$ and hence $k=\sqrt[3]{4}$, so $B$ should have been equal to $-\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{4}}$. But then I found out I already calculated $B$ so I cannot 'choose' it.

What is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** I think you're on the right track. If you have $$w^3+Bw+C=0$$ then use $$w=kv$$ and use a constant scaling factor $r$ on both sides to get
$$rk^3v^3 +Brkv +rC=0$$Now you just need to find $k$ and $r$ satisfying
$$\begin{cases}
rk^3 = 4\\Brk = -3
\end{cases}$$Then your $A$ is $rC$.

Comment: okay so then $k=\frac{4}{3}B$ right? (I chose $k=1$ and $r=4$)

Comment: I'm thinking now.. why did I use $w=kv$ then? Can you help?

Comment: You already performed the first step that eliminated the $z^2$ term, right? That step gave you $B$ and $C$ already -- it's known, you can't change it. Now in this step you scale the input (by $k$) and the output (by $r$) so that the other two variable terms have the coefficients you want. Note that dividing these two new equations will eliminate $r$ and you get $k$ in terms of $B$ (since you then have $k^2/B = -4/3$), and then you get $r$ by putting this $k$ back into one of these equations).

Comment: okay I get that.. so my answer is correct?

Comment: Please recompute your $B$ and $C$. I'm getting $B=-\frac13a^2+b$ and $C=\frac2{27}a^3-\frac13ab+c$.

Comment: yes you're right! thanks, I edited my question.